# Caching plugins + mod_pagespeed = overkill?

Tags: apache

After actively blogging for a couple of years, I stopped completely. Now, I have restarted blogging and am back on WordPress. Earlier, I was on a shared hosting and couldn't do much. Hence I used W3TC. Now, I am on a VPS and am a bit more technically sound. I now work on a LAMP stack with mod_pagespeed. Tinkering along, I have a 93/100 score on the Insights tool.

My question is - would using caching plugins like W3TC/WP-Super Cache,etc along with mod_pagespeed be an overkill?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say whether it is overkill or not.

Generally there are several type of caches need to be implemented, Opcache (for PHP codes), Query cache (for Database access), Object cache (for community type of website or shared server where content are constantly updated) and Page cache (for static content such as HTML). Until you understand all the differences and what exactly a plugin is doing, it hard to generalise to say it is overkill. Having said that, most of the plugins are implementing various types of caches that can be done with simple function or through services at the server level.

Personally I don't use a plugin for cache and implementing everything as 'native' as possible, I wrote a blog about [Implementing various cache](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2016/11/hosting-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-part-4-optimise-wordpress-through-cache/) on a Nginx WordPress server (in fact on a credit-size server that run my website). It may not applicable to LAMP solution, but I talked about the basic of various type of caches.